# Webservice sometimes does not respond to external requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an AspNet webservice, it all goes well when testing in localhost. I installed it to my server (windows server 2012), doing the requests in localhost works perfectly as expected, but when trying to access from outside, for example using the data of my phone, sometimes the webservice responses and sometimes don't.

I tried to increase the timeout without any luck. Also the request I'm making is just to test the connection without any database connection.

The code of Program:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static IWebHost host;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            if (isService)
            {
                var pathToExe =                   Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
                var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
            }

            var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(
                args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray());

            host = builder.Build();

            if (isService)            
                host.RunAsService();            
            else
                host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {                    
                    logging.AddEventLog();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                // Configure the app here.
                })
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

I expected the same behaviour as when I'm doing the request in localhost, I do understand that it will take more time for the server to respond, but sometimes just it doesn't.
 I've set the timeout to 1000 seconds and still no response. If the server never responded I would have thought I didn't open the port correctly, but I can't think what does it make responds only sometimes.

**EDIT:** I have a logging in the server and I do catch and log the exceptions, when the server does not respond there is no logging.

Comment: "It sometimes doesn't work" isn't really enough information to go on. There's no magic solution to that. There could be any number of causes. Are errors logged on the server in these cases? Are you catching and logging exceptions? Have you confirmed the request is even reaching the asp.net application? If there are other servers/network devices in between have you traced that the request is getting through?

Comment: Hi @ADyson, sorry I know I didn't give a lot of information, I will try to add more responding your comment. I do have a logging in my server and I do catch exceptions, when the server does not respond ther is no logging so I assume the request doesn't reach the server. The server is directly in my home so the only servers/network devices that the request goes throught are from the providers, if this is what you were asking, I'm pretty new in all this so my knowledge is limited sorry. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok. Are there any entries in the IIS logs on the server which correspond to the failed requests? And when it fails, in the client which is sending the request, do you get any kind of HTTP status back? Or does it just time out?

Comment: Also you say "from outside"...so you mean your phone is on its network data (not WiFi) and it can talk to the server on your home network, is that right? How did you configure that? Port forwarding on your router? Do you connect via IP address or did you set up a domain name and dynamic DNS? It could be that those are intermittently not responding. If your router logs incoming connections that might be useful data.

Comment: When ti fails I don't get an HTTP status back I always get Time Out. Yes, When I say "form outside" I mean I use the data from the phone. I did a port forwarding on my router from the router management page of our provider. I did connect via IP address not domain name. I will search how to look the router logs. Thanks

Comment: Obviously your setup is not something which domestic internet service provider companies particularly support, they don't like you to have incoming connections and don't provide much bandwidth for it. Possibly your request is simply being dropped by the ISP. I'm only speculating there, though. Router logs might give you more of a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay @ADyson, I was waiting for a friend to prepare a clean server to test. The problem was, as you said, the router. The firewall of the router sometimes dropped packages and this was the reason that it was intermittently responding. After testing on a server that was built on a network with a router without firewall everything worked fine.
Thanks for your time @ADyson